# How to add currency "$" input MDL (Material Design Lite)

Tags: html, css, material-design

How can i make to have a currency for example "$" or a text that a user can saw that to input and stay absolute.

But dont forget i need it to make on Material Design Lite

```
<!-- Textfield with Floating Label -->

<form action="#">
  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample3">
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">Text...</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use a pseudo element, like `::after`

```css
label::after {
  content: ' $'
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample3">
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">Text...</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

or `::before`

```css
label::before {
  content: '$ '
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample3">
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">Text...</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, i also found another solution but anyway thank you :)